# php SQL form grid select and counter

Tags: php, mysql, forms

!http://i63.tinypic.com/zn8z6x.png 
My assignment is to visualize this form into a website, with the possibilities of the form. 
This is for a chicken slaughterhouse, for checking the weights.
On the form you can insert a "weight range" for example 1000 grams.

Then it should be possible to select the possible weights from the grid.
If its all filled in, the data should be send to the database. 
For example if you selected +50, the database should register 1050 grams.

I'm not asking to make the form for me, but i AM asking if this is at least a bit possible.  **And if its possible, how to make a little start with the grid and counter**

 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: _I'm not asking to make the form for me_ then... _if its possible, how to make a little start with the grid and counter_ I thought you didn't want us to code it for you?

Comment: I just do not want to look like a lazy person who askes to make the whole thing. just a little help

Comment: No one will write your code for you if you're not paying them to.. Plus this isn't what SO is for. Get going with it, get your DB setup, if you get stuck then make a question with your code and people will help you.

Comment: That is not what i am implying.. but whatever, i got everything set up. Just don't know where to start with the grid thing and counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple grid-generation using table.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var cols = 10;
  var rowsMax = 100;
  var rowsMin = -100;
  var rowDiff = 20;
  var rowVal = rowsMax;
  var t = $('table');
  
  while (rowVal >= rowsMin) {
    var tr = '<tr>';
    for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      if (col == 0) {
        tr += '<td>'+rowVal+'</td>';
      }

      if (rowVal == rowsMax) {
        t.find('tfoot tr').append('<td class="col-'+col+'">0</td>');
      }
      tr += '<td><input type="radio" name="weigh['+col+']" data-col="'+col+'" value="'+rowVal+'"></td>';
    }
    tr += '</tr>';

    t.find('tbody').append(tr);
    
    rowVal -= rowDiff;
  }
  
  $('table tbody input').change(function () {
    $('tfoot .col-'+$(this).data('col')).text(parseInt($('#base').val()) + parseInt($(this).val()));
  })
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="base" placeholder="Enter weight base."/>g

<table>
  <tbody>
  
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! only question left is how to get all the total dates seperately?

Comment: @Maus You can use hidden field

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i've been trying some things with the hidden field, en tried POST and GET, but when i use POST i dont get anything, and when i use GET i get this value http://localhost/heijs/blah.php?col-0=&col-1=&%5B0%5D=80&%5B1%5D=80 weird values, not the numbers that were filled in? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Maus Check namings, it must be `someName[]` instead of just `[]`

Comment: <input type="number" name='col-0' class="col-0 hidden"> <input type="number" name='col-0' class="col-1 hidden"> this is what i have on names right now, and that is the name the element inspector gives to the value of the totals.. sorry i am not really that familiar with javascript